# Control golang annotations in thrift generated code

Tags: go, thrift

I have a message from thrift that I would like to be able to serialize into and out of json, but I don't want the generated json keys to match what is in the generated go code.

Is there a way to control what annotations are attached to the struct in the go code that thrift generates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scratch my previous answer - it's undocumented, but it IS possible, I found it by reading the compiler code. *Bah*.

But anyway, in thrift's master (1.0-dev), here's how it's done - using a `go.tag` annotation.

This piece of thrift code:

```
struct foo {
  1: string bar (go.tag = "json:\"baz\" yo:\"dawg\""),
  2: string bang
}
```

Generates the following Go code:

```
type Foo struct {
        Bar  string `thrift:"bar,1" json:"baz" yo:"dawg"`
        Bang string `thrift:"bang,2" json:"bang"`
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your patch proposal.

Comment: @JensG I'm assuming this is sarcastic, but I would be glad to document this stuff, where would you recommend to do it?

Comment: Not more than *Bah* ;-) A good place is the [language-specific README](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/go) which can be found in the normal repo under [`/lib/go/README.md`](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/go/README.md;hb=HEAD). We accept [patches and pull requests](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute) - thank you!

Comment: Will do. Oh, and I've already contributed a couple of patches to thrift :)

Comment: Did you make a pull request Not_a_Golfer? I ran into the same issue you did, and I didn't see any documentation in the readme so I made this pull request: https://github.com/apache/thrift/pull/1053

Comment: PR merged to master.